# Integral of angle between tangent and line

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a problem like this but still haven't figured out how to solve it or what this concept is called in math.

Let's say I have a continuous and differentiable curve $S: y=f(x)$ from $A$ to $B$. $L$ is an arbitrary line with the formula $y=ax+b$. For every point $M$ within $A-B$ in $S$, $\alpha$  is the angle between the tangent of $S$ at $M$ and $L$. What is $\int \alpha(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ from $A$ to $B$?
[image: Figure]

In fact I want to find the line(s) L where $\int \alpha(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is minimum. Thank you
I think this is unsolvable with math but easily do it with computer.
$\int \alpha(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ = $\int \arctan{a} \, \mathrm{d}x$ - $\int \arctan{f'(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x$
And the later part is complicated or unsolvable, I tried with wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your diagram actually doesn't show a curve $y=f(x)$ because it has more than one $y$ value for some values of $x$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose i was drawing with new tool and my eyes are very very tiny..

Comment: Sorry to hear about your eye problems. Have you tried anything to solve this problem yet? It looks rather straightforward.

Comment: @SuzuHirose could you give me a hint please :(

Comment: Hint: Calculate the slope of curve at point (x,y). Call it as tan$\theta$. Now slope of line is a= tan$\phi$. Use the formula of angle between two lines to get the tan of the angle between the curve and line at (x,y). It will depend on x and y.  Now you can integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\arctan(-x) = -\arctan(x)$ and $\arctan$ is strictly increasing, if
$$
\int_R\arctan(f(x))dx=0
$$
then it must be that
$$
\int_R f(x)dx=0
$$
So if you have a value of $a$ such that
$$
\int_A^B \arctan(a-f'(x)) dx = 0
$$
then you must also have
$$
\int_A^B (a-f'(x)) dx = 0
$$
so the solution is $a=f(B) - f(A)$.

Comment: Thanks @suzuhirose san for spending your time answering my silly question!

Comment: It was a bit more difficult than I thought it was.